# After two VScode updates the function import (cv or numpy) does not work, even selecting others python interpreter path

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code, import

I often use python in VScode. However, after two VScode updates, the import function (cv or numpy) is not working. I've tried using the `shift+command+p`  and `> python select interpret`e but none are working for these functions.

[image]

I tried use > `pip install pylint` but it didn't work.

[image]

How can I solve this problem? Has someone the same problem in VScode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is recommended to use a virtual environment to manage third-party packages and python versions more conveniently.**

1. Create a virtual environment with the following command

   ```
    python -m venv myenv
   ```

   [image]
2. After the command is completed, select the virtual environment interpreter just created in the **Select Interpreter** panel

   [image]
3. The new terminal can automatically activate the environment

   [image]

   [image]
4. Now there is no package installed in the new virtual environment, and an error occurs

   [image]
5. Install the `cv2` package in the new environment, and the error disappeared after installing the package

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Steps I would suggest to follow:

1. install the package again (cv2), even if it is installed.
2. check vs code if it has any updates for the python extension.
3. update vs code application.
4. restart vs code.

hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks, @Abed! I had tried, but did not work. However, I followed these steps:                                                                                                                                        ▶ python -V
Python 2.7.10

▶ python2 -V
Python 2.7.14

▶ python3 -V
Python 3.6.5

▶ pip2 -V
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

▶ pip3 -V
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

▶ pip --version
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)